# How to swap two images in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have created a currency converter app in Xamarin forms in which we have two Image controls that contain the country flags. Now, if the user clicks the swap button, the flags swap each other.

For example, the source of the first image will go to the second image, and vice versa.

```
<Image Source="usaflag.png" x:Name="Img1"/>
<Image Source="australiaflag.png" x:Name="Img2"/>
<Button Text="SWAP" x:Name="BtnSwap" Clicked="BtnSwap_OnClicked"/>
```

Here's my XAML Code. I know the we will write the swapping code in the code behind file. I am not using the MVVM style pattern so if you've any code regarding swapping then kindly share it with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so you want to swap two images in xamarin forms. Well, that's pretty simple!

You just need to add this code inside the `OnClick()` event of a button.

```
  private void BtnSwap_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
       var firstImage = Img1.Source;
       var secondImage = Img2.Source;
                
       Img2.Source = firstImage;  
       Img1.Source = secondImage;
  }
```

Comment: You can even do `(Img1.Source, Img2.Source) = (Img2.Source, Img1.Source);`.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can Bind the sources and change those values on `BtnSwap_OnClicked`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).